# Equivalent adb command for MonkeyDevice.installPackage() method

Tags: android, python, adb, monkeyrunner

Is there exist any **adb** equivalent command for `MonkeyDevice.installPackage()` method?

By using the `installPackage()`method in python script for **monkeyrunner** I'm able to install **apk** successfully.

But when i use the command:

```
adb install ApkFileName.apk
```

it returns **protocol failure** message. So what kinds of protocol used by **monkeyrunner** tool to execute `installPackage()` method successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try what Android Studio does to install the APK

```
$ adb push ApkFileName.apk /data/local/tmp/apkfilename
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/apkfilename"
```

Comment: I think push and install use the same protocol, but monkeyrunner follow different. In here push work like that, copying apk file into target device, then installing it. I have tried many form of adb command including install, push.

Comment: From your comment, I cannot tell whether this works or not